# Autowiring not working for @Repository

Tags: spring, repository

I am trying to create a Simple REST service that stores data in the db. This is a sample architecture going from REST controller to a MVC-Controller, which instantiates an Entity and tries to store it in the db via an autowired Repository.
The REST service is correctly invoked and replies what it has to; however, storing the entity fails and the autowired repository is null. 
Can somebody help?

**My REST service:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/coord")
public class CoordService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMuseo(@PathVariable String name) {
        String result = "Hello " + name + ", I am saving on the db.";
        new CoordController().saveCoord();

        return result;
    }
}
```

**My application business logic (controller in MVC):**

```
@Component
public class CoordController {
    @Autowired
    private CoordRepository coordRepository;

    public void saveCoord() {
        System.out.println("Ok controller");

        Coord cg = new Coord();
        System.out.println("Ok new");
        cg.setCoord("xyz");
        cg.setId(1L);

        if (coordRepository == null) {
            System.out.println("REP NULL!");
        } else
            coordRepository.save(cg);

        System.out.println("Ok save()");
    }
}
```

**My Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Configurable
public class Coord extends IdentifiableEntity {

    @NotNull
    private String coord;

    public String getCoord() {
        return this.coord;
    }

    public void setCoord(String coord) {
        this.coord = coord;
    }
}
```

**My Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface CoordRepository extends
    JpaSpecificationExecutor<Coord>,
    JpaRepository<Coord, Long> {
}
```

**My applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:spring/*.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.lh.clte" />


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="3" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.lh.clte.repository" />
</beans>
```

**My persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
new CoordController().saveCoord();
```

You need to autowire your CoordController into your CoordService. By using new CoordController(), you are creating an instance of CoordController not managed by spring so its fields are not autowired.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/coord")
public class CoordService {

    @Autowired
    private CoordController coordController;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMuseo(@PathVariable String name) {
        String result = "Hello " + name + ", I am saving on the db.";
        coordController.saveCoord();

        return result;
    }
}
```

By the way, your CoordService class should be named CoordController since its a controller (it has the @RestController annotation!) and your CoordController should be CoordService since it contains business logic.

Comment: Ops, thanks, I wonder how could miss that! However, I agree with you on the terminology issue only if you want to stay with Spring dictionary. In literature, the controller does not refer to the "web controller" (be it REST or not), but rather to the business logic. For this reason, in contrast to Spring, I like to call "controller" what Spring would annotate with @Service.